# TypeError: Cannot read property 'getEventById' of null

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

At first, I am a very new programmer, so I apologize for my ignorance. I wrote this code using google apps script to take data from a google sheet, and import that to a calendar.

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Class");
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var today = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+9", "yyyy-MM-dd");

function caldel() {
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('//gmail address'); 
  for (var i=73; data.length; i++) {
    var evtcall = eventCal.getEventById(data[i][52]);
    evtcall.deleteEvent();

  }
}
```

It used to run well, but today, error message poped up.

```
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'getEventById' of null
caldel  @ Code.gs:8"
```

I don't know why this error came out. If there is anyone who knows or fixes this error, plz help me. Thank you.

Comment: This error means that the `CalendarApp.getCalendarById('//gmail address');` did return `null` therefore there is nothing to get on the `getEventById`. Can you check what is returned by using `Logger.log(eventCal)` under the `CalendarApp` line?

Answer (score 0):

Assumming that you are using a real calendar id (like Gmail address) in

```
var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('//gmail address');
```

you are getting `null` assigned to `eventCal` because the *effective user* don't have access to the referred calendar.

1. Validate that you can access the calendar with the account that you are using to run the script.

As a rule of thumb avoid sign-in into multiple accounts when running a Google Apps Script function. This because calling a server-side function from a dialog, sidebar or web-app might be done using the default account instead of the account that has access to the required resources.